# What is a gender-neutral alternative to the expression "man-days"?

Tags: gender-neutral, political-correctness

What is a gender-neutral alternative to the expression "man-days"? I thought of "work-days" but am wondering if there might be another term. The use would be, for instance, "This project requires staffing of 1000 man-days over a six-month period."

Comment: Is *man-day* really used?-- I'm a native English speaker and can't recall this being used despite that *man-**hour*** seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: This question contains the assumption that "man-day" is not gender-neutral. However it is. The question should really ask *"What is a term for "man-day" without referencing gender?"*

Comment: Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the post,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: As far as my research, Man-days dont have any Gender associated with it. If people were educated with historic facts that it has derived from manual days  ->  they have different meanings. Manual goes back to a word meaning “hand,” and refers to something being done by hand. It comes to English from Latin. The word man is Germanic, not Latin, and its history goes back through Old English.

Answer (score 27):

*Person-hour* or *person-day* are gender-neutral alternatives suggested by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-hour).

Comment: And since OP is asking about days, *person-day* is a term I've heard and used.

Answer (score 23):

If we’re talking labour, you could use *worker-days*, because in this context, *worker* is a better fix than *person*.

Comment: This is different from "work-days" in that you're still talking about people.

Answer (score 21):

For software efforts, I like "developer days". Sure, it's longer, but it alliterates nicely, and can be abbreviated to "dev days" once everyone in the organization is familiar with the term.

Comment: Very nice: Gender neutral while not artificial PC, so nobody can complain. (Also tells you that it doesn't count manager days, tester days, marketing days etc. ).

Comment: A problem with this is that you can't say the whole project will take X developer days, because some of the effort will go into testing, project management, etc.

Answer (score 13):

We use *labor days*.  The *man-hour* has become the *labor-hour*.

Comment: Isn't there only one labour day a year, though?

Comment: @JoeZeng - that explains the progress on some of my projects

Comment: @JoeZeng - In case you're serious, the holiday is capitalized. And, as a matter of fact. Labour Day is celebrated on many different dates in various countries. So there are actually many Labour Days.

Comment: ^ Nah, I was just joking.

Comment: With man-hour or person-hour, you multiply the people times the hours to get the man-hours.  Just like foot-pounds, acre-feet, or kilowatt-hours. Miles/gallon or stitches/inch follow a similar convention.  Labor isn't already a unit that is used to measure anything.

Answer (score 7):

Surely *man hours* or *man days* are both acceptable. You say you want a "gender neutral" alternative, but these forms are unmarked, much like we use *mankind* when talking about all people, not just those who are male. If you use a term like *people days* you might risk being ambiguous and waste time explaining your new word that could be spent on this massive project!

Comment: What possible ambiguity is there in "people-days"?

Comment: This is an argument, not an answer.

Comment: Actually, there really are people who think that *mankind* is offensively sexist.

Comment: @tchrist: They’re on the wrong side of historical etymology (*man* ~ *person*, *wyf* ~ *female*, *wer* ~ *male*), though probably the right side of good intentions.

Comment: @Jon: And we all know what good intentions lead to.

Comment: Historic or herstoric etymology? Aiggh, the pain! Why did I do that? Why am I hitting ent...

Comment: Downvoted because it's completely non-responsive to the question.

Comment: @Eric; There's a joke there about *historical* vs *hysterical*. Fortunately I am too responsible to make it.

Comment: @horatio you're right in that I could have been abit clearer. My answer is that an alternative isn't necessary and I don't believe there to be one in popular use.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes use the phrase "days of effort" as in:

> This task will take about 20 days of effort.

Comment: Not clear whether that means the team will need 20 days, or the 5-member team will need 4 days.

Answer (score 2):

Since the phrase "staff years" is fairly common, I expect it would be well-understood to say "staff days". This avoids the ambiguity of "work days", which *could* be understood to mean Monday-Friday (depending on how clear the context is).

Answer (score 2):

Days of effort is probably the most accurate. Work-days is shorter. Labour(or labor)days sounds more manual. Developer days is fine if you *want* to only look at part of the job, but Analysis days, Tester days etc would be needed too.
I did wonder if Lady Days for the next hundred years would redress the balance (no, being 'humourous', or not). Man days does automatically make people think of the male first, so we do need something else, but it needs to clearly mean number of actual days of effort so people don't misinterpret as 'time to delivery'. It needs to be acceptable to feminists and misogynists alike.
Work-days is what I'd vote for; I guess we'll see what gets into general use.

Since these development efforts are usually for comparison with other projects, Jira's idea of using points to indicate level of effort without saying directly it will take 5 days (and then being taken to task because it took 5.5 days) is a useful one, if people can be persuaded to use it properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Effort-Days** has been my best and I have used it for over 30 years now. It is also recommended by a number of multilateral and multi-national organizations.

Comment: References to the numerous organizations that recommend this would vastly improve this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the context is labuor generally, I would suggest "work days".

Comment: Please add objective sources to your answer to substantiate it. Have a look at the help center to find out about good answers.

Answer (score -1):

"Personnel hours" or "staff bandwidth" are good alternatives.

Comment: Who uses "staff bandwidth" to represent man-days?

Comment: Could you add some references of where these have been used in the wild?